# Is it possible to check the code for a Google Chrome extension before installing it?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Google Chrome extensions are a nice invention, [but they can potentially interact with a lot of user information](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=30636989775092ba&hl=en).

**Is it possible to browse their manifest and/or their source code before installing them?**

The reason I'm asking this on StackOverflow is that I've just developed my first extension. Since it's manipulating the CSS style for the websites you visit, just before the installation it will prompt:

> "This extension will have access to
>   your browsing history and private data
>   on all websites"

Pretty scaring... I can imagine lot of users not installing the extension just because of this message. I would be really happy to show them what my extension is doing and how safe it is...

Comment: The problem is that even if you check it before install, it can always be auto-updated with some evilness later, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google Chrome extensions are zip files with a different extension and some metadata. If you rename them to a .zip file and extract, you'll be able to get at the Javascript code and HTML behind them.

For more information, refer to the [developer documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html).

Unfortunately, just because the user *can* look at the source code, doesn't mean they'll understand it.

Comment: Thanks. I had to unzip the file via "unzip" rather than the Mac Archive Utility (which was just creating looped zip files) but it worked. Awesome. Oh, I agree about your last sentence, but the extension is mostly aimed at developers, so...

Comment: Incidentally, the same trick works on firefox extensions (however, note that in their case there's multiple layers of zipping)

Answer (score 3):

There's an awesome extension for this very purpose....
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bbamfloeabgknfklmgbpjcgofcokhpia#

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look to it.

Comment: the link does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can create a description for your extension. Tell the users about your extension there (they see it when they browse the extensions website), publish your code somewhere and link to it :)